# Adding a Metadata Attribute class breaks my Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`enter code here`I am new to MVC and I wanted to try the Metadata Type attributes for validation. My problem is that when I add the attributes to the class I get an exception when I call the UpdateModel method.

```
    public class SpaceMetadata
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        [StringLength(22, ErrorMessage = "Name must be less than 23 characters.")]
        public string Spacename { get; set; }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(SpaceMetadata))]
    public partial class Space
    { }
```

The exception says that it cannot update the model.
I realize that I have validate input to false but that 
because I am allowing html to be entered into a textarea. 
That shouldn't be the problem though, right? What am I doing wrong?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SpaceCreate(FormCollection formValues)
    {
        var space = new Space();
        UpdateModel(space);
```

Comment: Please post the precise ModelState Error being generated. P.S. I tend to use TryUpdateModel instead, much easier to control a breakdown gracefully.

Comment: Yea, TryUpdateModel did the trick. Thanks.